# PHPexcel: Combine two variables into one cell

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to create an excel sheet with data from a mysql database.

At some point I want to combine two variables into one cell.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$customer = $row["city"].' '.$row["name"]; // Doesn't work

$rowNumber = 2;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $col = 'A'; 
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$rowNumber, $row['routenr']);
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$rowNumber, $date);
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('D'.$rowNumber, $customer);
       $rowNumber++;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example won't work because you're concatenating `$row["city"]` and `$row["name"]` **before** you've retrieved $row from the database result set. Nothing to do with PHPExcel, just basic PHP.

Move your concatenation **inside** the while loop so that `$row["city"]` and `$row["name"]` will be populated with actual values from the retrieved row

```
$rowNumber = 2;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $customer = $row["city"].' '.$row["name"];
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$rowNumber, $row['routenr']);
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$rowNumber, $date);
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('D'.$rowNumber, $customer);
   $rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out.. I already thought I was overlooking something!

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
$rowNumber = 2;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $customer = $row["city"].' '.$row["name"];
       $col = 'A'; 
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$rowNumber, $row['routenr']);
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$rowNumber, $date);
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('D'.$rowNumber, $customer);
       $rowNumber++;
}
```